# Error Extracting content from Internet Explorer 8 vs Internet Explorer 9

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have some VBA code that in effect launches a web page and reads of the data content.

```html
Sub Retrieve_Info()
        
        If First_Time = True Then
            IE_Sledgehammer
            Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            IE.Visible = True
        End If
        
            PACN = Cells(Row, 1)
            IE.Navigate "http://www.myWebReportPage.com/Apps/AddIssues/EditIssue.asp?IssueID=" & PACN & "&ProjectID=PACN"
        If First_Time = True Then
            Sleep 10000
            First_Time = False
        Else
            Sleep 3000
        End If
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Source_Code = IE.document.DocumentElement.innerText
        Do Until InStr(1, Source_Code, "Issue Id") <> 0 Or InStr(1, Source_Code, "Unable to locate") <> 0
            Source_Code = IE.document.DocumentElement.innerText
            Sleep 100
        Loop
        
        Sleep 200
            
        Source_Code = IE.document.DocumentElement.innerText
        Source_Code2 = IE.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML
            
End Sub
```

The problem is that this code runs fine in IE 8 but hangs in IE9.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi,  I get the same with one of my projects.  You can use the IE readystate etc to check for the page loading rather than sleeps.  Something like      Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop I am looking at this today, but it's hard to replicate, as it happens infrequently.  I'll let you know what I find.  I also use the actual libraries,Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: Glad I am not the only one. Look forward to your views later. Thxs